# Failed to call GetTypes on assembly Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I installed march 2013 CU for Sharepoint 2013 and after that I get:

> Failed to call GetTypes on assembly
>   Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c. Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.ProcessImageInfo
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.IImagingAdapter.ProcessImage(System.IO.Stream,
>   Double, Double)'.

What is this? I see it is related with the machine translation service. I checked this service and it was run. Since I don't use it I deleted this service. Now I get this error everytime I try to do smth on central admin

**EDIT**
By delete I mean: I went to central admin -> Manage Service applications -> Selected Machine Translation Service and deleted.

But if I try to recreate using CA it gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldnt delete a service becasue you dont use it ;), you should go into services and disable it if you belive that you dont use it!

have you tried iisreset? or restarting your server? i presume its a test server? also as important when you say you removed it, what did you do exactly to remove the service? are you talking about services.msc? or from a folder or from central admin? knowing what you did we can add it back in and solve the current issue.

also like to note that have you updated sharepoint server to october? or is it only at march update? if so you need to update it to the latest version, you need the march update to update to any other latest update!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/jj891062.aspx

its indicating that your using a build version of 15.0.0.0 on assembly Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices but it should be at a higher build.

goto:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Web.Common\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\

now find the assembly Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices and right click, select properties and than check its build version! I think the build version is ment to be higher than just 15.0.0.0

a bit about the service you removed:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.translationservices.aspx

lets see if you can get it running again:

run the following in powershell:

```
$tj = get-sptimerjob "Sharepoint Translation Services"
$tj.Runnow()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163145

did you run SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard after the update? any update you make you need to run SharePoint 2013 Products Configuration Wizard.

if that powershell code fails than you need to run:

```
installutil assemblyname.exe
```

assemblyname.exe is the dll name of Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices located within C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Web.Common\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(v=vs.110).aspx

when its successful you can then go into services and disable not delete ;).

to sort the original issue out you either run microsoft office repair or sharepoint 2013 repair

for sharepoint 2013 repair

Control Panel -> Programs and Features for SharePoint Server 2013

any issues run powershell command from here:

http://stevemannspath.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-repairing-installation.html

**EDIT**

based on the answers you have given me i would say that there is a conflict between central admin that is looking for dll version 15.0.0.0 and what you actually have on the file system which is 15.0.4505.1000 and obviously its failing when its looking for a method that doesnt exist in the new version which you have!

to try and get around this issue as you cant seem to add the service back in you could try going to central admin web.config:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\

goto the above location and then go into the central admin folder (usual named from its port number which you can see in the url of central admin page)

once you have opend it up you can scroll down till you see the web.config file, open it with your selected text application like notepad or notepad++ and look for the dll  Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.

once you have found the dll  Microsoft.Office.Web.Common you can change the buil version from 15.0.0.0 to 15.0.4505.1000. now save and exit.

do an iisreset and try to add the service back in again! lets hope this simple trick works!

Comment: Edited the question and yes it is a test environment

Comment: ok iv got more of an understanding of what you have done makes it easier to know what todo! so what did you do to try and add it back again? through powershell?

Comment: i presume that you used powershell and that you used the ui by clicking on the new button and selecting the service in question? if so as iv noted above make sure that your dll is the correct version first

Comment: I've tried to recreate the service running the configuration wizard but this error is displayed.

Comment: The file version is: 15.0.4505.1000

Comment: i think that is the issue right there! the origional issue was that it was failing due to the running service was different to the current version and now you have removed that service version 15 and trying to add it back its a totaly different version to the one it want. so its looking for 15.0.0.0 but you have 15.0.4505.1000 which is the correct version!

Comment: sorry the build version according .net reflector is: Microsoft.Office.Web.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c , while the file version: right click, select properties is 15.0.4505.1000

Comment: yes as i suspected there is a missmatch between the two!

Comment: @MIlena just updated my answer

Comment: I'll do this right away the June update is finished

Comment: Since update is still running, I was snicking around and I found out that the file version changed to: 15.0.4517.1003 and it changed before 10 min. Thus the update is making some changes over this dll.

Comment: nice! hopefully this will solve both of your issues :)

Comment: Ok it is still there. I'll edit the web.config as you suggested.

Comment: I can't find the Microsoft.Office.Web.Common on web.config for the Central Admin Web App

Comment: i found a better method! ;) instead we should let sharepoint handle the correction! todo this goto central admin -> Configuration Wizards -> Launch the Farm Configuration Wizard -> follow each stage! you should see a section called services which is what you want to restore back! do that and finish, once finished loading click skip and your all set

Comment: YES, I did that but it doesn't finish because it raises the error "Failed to call GetTypes on assembly Microsoft.Office.TranslationServices". That is so strangeee!!!

Comment: thats a shame! have you taken any backup of the server? you could rollback the services part from backup if you have?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428305.aspx

Comment: i have another method: go to central admin -> application managment -> under Service Applications click on Service Application Associations click on the webapp and make sure its check and then ok. Otherwise you need to restore the dll. todo this goto the dll loction right click the file and click restore previous versions. If not last option isto restore sharepoint server repair, goto program and features-> uninstall a program -> click on sharepoint server -> click change or repair and follow the wizard to repair ;)

Comment: Finally decided to re install sharepoint